# Convertir un dato que me viene .Ejemplo me viene 30 o 30.5 y convertirlo 30:00 y 30:30 , para poder interpretar el valor que me viene para carreras

Tags: extjs, sencha

```
onCambioCarrera: function (value,label, layoutContext) {

// var value = layoutContext.renderer(label);
      //  value = 30.50;
        if (value) {
            var arrayValue = value.split("."); arrayValue = [30, 50];
            var segundos = 00;
            if (arrayValue(1) == 50) { segundos = 30 }
            var resultado = arrayValue(0) + ":" + segundos;
            return resultado;
        }
```

**
},
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

esto te puede servir:

```js
function formatValue(value) {
  let floorValue = Math.floor(value);
  let seconds = Math.floor((value - floorValue) * 60);

  floorValue = floorValue < 10 ? `0${floorValue}` : floorValue;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
  return `${floorValue}:${seconds}`;
}
console.log(formatValue(30.03));
console.log(formatValue(30.25));
console.log(formatValue(30.5));
console.log(formatValue(30.75));
console.log(formatValue(30.99));
```

Comment: lo he probado y funciona genial.